# facing challenge in previous function in javaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to desing a template which contains various countries information. and when clicked on the specific country respected cities of that country are displayed with it's information and hides the country div.

Here's My HTML: `

```
<div id="first">
    <div id="country"></div>
</div>

<div id="second">

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="Content">
            <div class="Heading">
                <i class="fa fa-home home-button"></i>
                <p id="Name">CHENNAI</p>
            </div>
            <div id="cityImage"><img src="images/chennai.jpg"></div>
            <div id="cityInfo">Chennai, on the Bay of Bengal in eastern India, is the capital of the state of Tamil
                Nadu.
                The city is home to Fort St. George, built in 1644 and now a museum showcasing the city’s roots as a
                British military
                garrison and East India Company trading outpost, when it was called Madras. Religious sites include
                Kapaleeshwarar Temple,
                adorned with carved and painted gods, and St. Mary’s, a 17th-century Anglican church.
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="Thumbnail"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="navigationPanel">
        <div class="navigationBtn prevBtn" id="prevBtn" onclick="Prev()"></div>
        <div class="navigationBtn nextBtn" id="nextBtn" onclick="Next()"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`

I am facing challenge in the previous function here means when clicked on the previous button then it comes to the previous country's first city rahter than last city.

Here's My JavaScript: `

```
  var categoryIndex = 0;
  var cl;
  var country = city_data.countryList;
  var city_list;
  var cindex;
  for (i = 0; i < country.length; i++) 
  {
      c = '<div class="country-item" onclick="show_city(' + i + ')">' +
    '<img class="country-img" src="' + country[i].countryThumbnail + '"><br>' +
    '<span class="country-name">' + country[i].countryName + '</span>' +
    '</div>';

     $("#country").append(c);
   }

   function show_city(i) {
   cindex = i;
   city_list = country[i].cityList;
   categoryIndex = 0;
   $('#first').hide('');
   for (var i = 0; i < city_list.length; i++) {
    cl = i == 0 ? 'iconSelected' : '';

    $("#Thumbnail").append("<div class='menu' id='menu" + i + "' 
     menuIndex='" + i + "'><div class='thumbnail-img'><img src=" + 
     city_list[i].imageThumbnail + " class='border " + cl + "' 
     id='border" + i + "' imageThumbnail'></div><div 
     id='thumbnailName'>" + city_list[i].cityName + "</div></div>");
   }
   show();
   $('#second').show('');

   $("#Thumbnail").find(".menu").on('click',  function () {
    categoryIndex = $(this).attr('menuIndex');
    show();
  })
}

function show() {
$('.border').removeClass('iconSelected');
$('#border' + categoryIndex).addClass('iconSelected');

$('#Content').find('#Name').html(city_list[categoryIndex].cityName);
$('#Content').find('#cityImage').find('img').attr('src', 
city_list[categoryIndex].imageBanner);

$('#Content').find('#cityInfo').html(city_list[categoryIndex].
 description);
}

function Prev() {
if (categoryIndex > 0) {
    categoryIndex--;
    show();
} else if(cindex > 0){
    $("#Thumbnail").html('');
    show_city(--cindex);
}
}

function Next() {
if (categoryIndex < city_list.length - 1) {
    categoryIndex++; 
    $("#prevBtn").css({opacity : 1});
    show();
} else if (cindex < country.length - 1) {
    $("#Thumbnail").html('');
    show_city(++cindex);
}

 }


$('.home-button').click(function () {
$('#second').hide('');
$("#Thumbnail").html('');
$('#first').show('');
});
```

`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I can't tell what's wrong here without more code. Can you please update your question so that it shows all your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)  :)

Comment: Thanks for your edit, but it's still unclear. What is `categoryIndex`, `city_list`, `cIndex`, and `country`? What do the functions `show` and `show_city` do? What are the HTML elements? Can you see if you can use SO's snippet tool to create a runnable example?